# Service not catching SessionChange events

Tags: c#, events, service

I'm writting a small service supposed to log some events. However only two of them or working and even after searching I can't figure out why.

These are the events I want to log:

- Starting computer **WORKING**
- Session locking
- Session unlocking
- Shutdown computer **WORKING**

---

I triple checked that my service could catch those events (I even set all *CanHandle..* to true..

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    // 
    // Service1
    // 
    this.CanHandlePowerEvent = true;
    this.CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
    this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
    this.CanShutdown = true;
    this.ServiceName = "TimeToGoService";
}
```

This my overrided **OnSessionChange()**

```
protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
{
    if (changeDescription.Reason == SessionChangeReason.SessionLock)
    {
        startBreak();
    }
    else if (changeDescription.Reason == SessionChangeReason.SessionUnlock)
    {
        endBreak();
    }

    base.OnSessionChange(changeDescription);
}
```

**startBreak()** and **endBreak()** are only writing logs to a file with a StreamWriter..

By searching on the web, I saw some people using a hidden form for those events to be fired. Is that the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but the code above is now working 100%. Probably have missed something..

**EDIT:** Not being able to identify exactly what was wrong. I can give to my next one the service config that works beside the code.

- Service user is **LocalSystem**
- CanHandleSessionChangingEvents set to **true**

And.. That's pretty much it. Notice that service does not need to *interact with desktop* to catch those events.

Moreover, you can check if your services is getting events from terminal in **EventObserver**, you'll see if they failed or if they succeed.

Good luck, but if you use code and configuration above, you should be able to make it work ;)

Comment: nothing wrong with your code... there are lots of posts that deal with OnSessionChange not being reliable.